# Foreach() array.each() in coldfusion...backwards for array and struct? What gives?

Tags: arrays, struct, coldfusion

In php, whether array or struct(associative array) you just do this:

```
foreach ($ra as $key=>$value){}
```

and for an array you get `1=>first value, 2=>second value, etc`.  For a 'struct', you get `firstkey=>first value, secondkey=>second value, etc`.

In ColdFusion:

```
ra = {'key1'='val1','key2'='val2'};    
ra.each(function(value, key) {
    writeOutput("#key# => #value#<br />");
});

ra = ['one','two'];    
ra.each(function(value, key) {
    writeOutput("#key# => #value#<br />");
});
```

and you get:

```
val1 => key1
val2 => key2    
1 => one
2 => two
```

I'm getting the value (val1) where I am expecting the key (key1)
So, what am I doing wrong?  Am I setting up my struct backwards?  Does coldfusion just do `each()` opposite, for array/struct?

Answer, via @Leigh: Yes, theyre back-asswards.  Here is how to deal:

```
if(isStruct(ra)){
    ra.each(function(key, value) {
        writeOutput("#key# => #value#<br />");
    });     
}else{//aray
    arrayeach(ra, function(value, key) {
        writeOutput("#key# => #value#<br />");
    });     
}
```

Comment: Iterating through CF structures have no *guaranteed* order. Though supposedly that has changed (somewhat) in 2016. See [structNew("ordered")](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-s/structnew.html)

Comment: I see, but my question is not about the order, it's about the key and value, in the callback function of each().

Comment: Duh! Sorry, totally misread that.

Comment: (Edit) Did you mean to write ..? `ra.each(function(key, value) {` rather than `ra.each(function(value, key) {` See [StructEach](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-s/structeach.html).

Comment: Well, yeah, that's what I was confusded, on.  Seems like it acts different, array vs struct.  Try that code, please, if you have a sec.

Comment: (Edit) Yes, I had tested it and got the same result as you. I have not used member functions much, that is why I pointed to the docs on [StructEach](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-s/structeach.html), see also [ArrayEach](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-a-b/arrayeach.html).  From what I read, you are correct in that the expected parameter positions are different. For struct it is `function(key, value)` and for arrays it seems to be `function(value, index)`.

Comment: Ok, I see what youre showing me, when i scroll down.  Ugh...I guess I'll have to test the var, before each()ing it.  This has come up, for a debugging function, where i email myself variables, which might be a struct, that I set up, or could just be an array that is present, at that point of the code.

Comment: Gotcha. FWIW, they both allow a third argument (which contains the object ie struct/array), ie `function(key, value, obj)`. Though not sure that helps much. Probably simpler to test the variable before each().

Comment: Since you had basically figured it out already, may as well post that as an "answer" (w/links to the docs in case someone else has similar questions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback functions are conveniently backwards from each other.  Here is how you can deal with it:

```
if(isStruct(ra)){
    ra.each(function(key, value) {
        writeOutput("#key# => #value#<br />");
    });     
}else{//aray
    arrayeach(ra, function(value, key) {
        writeOutput("#key# => #value#<br />");
    });     
}
```